# XML to SQL - Selecting multiple nodes with the same name

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have working code that can select a few values from an XML file. The problem is that I have multiple nodes with the same name.

Here is a snippet of the XML:

```
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/Countries_and_Their_Address_Components_Summary">
  <wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Country wd:Descriptor="Afghanistan">
      <wd:ID wd:type="WID">db69b722446c11de98360015c5e6daf6</wd:ID>
      <wd:ID wd:type="ISO_3166-1_Alpha-2_Code">AF</wd:ID>
      <wd:ID wd:type="ISO_3166-1_Alpha-3_Code">AFG</wd:ID>
      <wd:ID wd:type="ISO_3166-1_Numeric-3_Code">4</wd:ID>
    </wd:Country>
    <wd:Address_Format_Type wd:Descriptor="Basic">
      <wd:ID wd:type="WID">4516bf435611423ea4ee72fa842572a0</wd:ID>
    </wd:Address_Format_Type>
    <wd:Local>1</wd:Local>
    <wd:Address_Components>
      <wd:Address_Component wd:Descriptor="Address Line 1 - Local">
        <wd:ID wd:type="WID">12d859b8df024175a111da2e088250fb</wd:ID>
        <wd:ID wd:type="Address_Component_Type_ID">ADDRESS_LINE_1_LOCAL</wd:ID>
      </wd:Address_Component>
      <wd:Order>a</wd:Order>
      <wd:Required>0</wd:Required>
    </wd:Address_Components>
    <wd:Address_Components>
      <wd:Address_Component wd:Descriptor="Address Line 2 - Local">
        <wd:ID wd:type="WID">85a6ab9412c44dd9a71a7e4760bf17fb</wd:ID>
        <wd:ID wd:type="Address_Component_Type_ID">ADDRESS_LINE_2_LOCAL</wd:ID>
      </wd:Address_Component>
      <wd:Order>b</wd:Order>
      <wd:Required>0</wd:Required>
    </wd:Address_Components>
```

My SQL is the following:

```
declare @inputxml table (x xml)

insert @inputxml
select x
from OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\ParallelTool\addcomp.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) As T(x)

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'urn:com.workday.report/Countries_and_Their_Address_Components_Summary')
    select 
        xmldata.[ISO], xmldata.[Component 1], xmldata.[Component 2], xmldata.[Required]
    into dbo.WD
    from @inputxml
    cross apply (
        select 
            [ISO] = xmldata.value('(Country/ID)[3]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'),
            [Component 1] = xmldata.value('(Address_Components/Address_Component/ID)[2]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'),
            [Component 2] = xmldata.value('(Address_Components/Address_Component/ID)[2]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'),
            [Required] = xmldata.value('(Address_Components/Required)[1]', 'INT')
        from x.nodes('/Report_Data/Report_Entry') Z1(xmldata)
    ) xmldata
```

Where I can't get what I need is the [Component 2]. I want to basically select ALL of the "Address_Component_Type_ID" in the file, but they are all named the same and under other nodes that are named the same. How can I specify in my SQL to grab all of the Component Types? Thank you for looking!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends what you want to do...  If you know there are exactly 2 "Address_Components" that you want to grab, you can modify your query like so:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'urn:com.workday.report/Countries_and_Their_Address_Components_Summary')
    select 
        xmldata.[ISO], xmldata.[Component 1], xmldata.[Component 2], xmldata.[Required]
    from @inputxml
    cross apply (
        select 
            [ISO] = xmldata.value('(Country/ID)[3]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'),
            [Component 1] = xmldata.value('(Address_Components/Address_Component/ID)[2]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'),
            [Component 2] = xmldata.value('(Address_Components[2]/Address_Component/ID)[2]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'),
            [Required] = xmldata.value('(Address_Components/Required)[1]', 'INT')
        from x.nodes('/Report_Data/Report_Entry') Z1(xmldata)
    ) xmldata
```

And the results look like this:

```
ISO   Component 1               Component 2               Required
----- ------------------------- ------------------------- -----------
AFG   ADDRESS_LINE_1_LOCAL      ADDRESS_LINE_2_LOCAL      0
```

However, if there can be any number of "Address_Components", and you want to grab them into separate records, you can rewrite your query like this:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'urn:com.workday.report/Countries_and_Their_Address_Components_Summary')
    select 
        [ISO] = Report_Entry.x.value('(Country/ID)[3]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
        , [Component] = Address_Components.x.value('(Address_Component/ID)[2]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
        , [Required] = Address_Components.x.value('(Required)[1]', 'INT')
    from @inputxml
    cross apply x.nodes('/Report_Data/Report_Entry') Report_Entry(x)
    cross apply Report_Entry.x.nodes('./Address_Components') Address_Components (x)
```

And the results look like this:

```
ISO   Component                 Required
----- ------------------------- -----------
AFG   ADDRESS_LINE_1_LOCAL      0
AFG   ADDRESS_LINE_2_LOCAL      0
```

Comment: This is great. It definitely is a huge step in the right direction of what I need. You cannot tell by the snippet that I linked, but I actually have multiple ISO's. For that reason, when I use cross apply, I am multiplying everything out to include duplicates. Instead of only getting 1300 rows, I am getting 299,000 rows (230 ISO's * 1300 address components). it is essentially cross applying to every node rather than just the ones in the current node. I've been playing with it for a while with no luck. Is there anyway to get it to only cross apply within the current ISO?

Comment: To further clarify, it's not exactly duplicates. I worded that incorrectly - they appear to be duplicates. But what it is doing is grabbing every single address component int the file and applying it up to every single ISO, where I only want the address components from WITHIN the respective ISO.

Comment: @bheltzel You are right. The way I wrote the cross apply to the Address_Components, it was pulling all address components from the root, instead of just the subelements of the current ISO element. I corrected it now.  If it works for you, please mark the answer as correct.