# SQL Server parse XML to table - multiple node with the same name

Tags: sql-server, xml, parsing

I would like to parse XML into a table in SQL Server 2012 where my XML has nodes with the same name.

My SQL query which return only the first row:

```
SELECT
    [date] = Node.Data.value('(date)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
    name = Node.Data.value('(name)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
FROM    
    @xml.nodes('result/subject') Node(Data)
```

XML sample

```
<result>
  <subject>
    <date>2019-06-03</date>
    <name>AZGREX</name>
    <name>ABGDFC</name>
    <name>WWGDFW</name>
    <name>FDSFSD</name>
    <name>FSDWEW</name>
    <name>CXZCXZ</name>
    <name>GWGRE</name>
  </subject>
</result>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XML to SQL - Selecting multiple nodes with the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22178863/xml-to-sql-selecting-multiple-nodes-with-the-same-name)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `nodes` in the `FROM`:

```sql
DECLARE @XML xml = '<result>
  <subject>
    <date>2019-06-03</date>
    <name>AZGREX</name>
    <name>ABGDFC</name>
    <name>WWGDFW</name>
    <name>FDSFSD</name>
    <name>FSDWEW</name>
    <name>CXZCXZ</name>
    <name>GWGRE</name>
  </subject>
</result>';

SELECT r.[subject].value('(date/text())[1]','date') AS [date],
       s.[name].value('(./text())[1]','varchar(6)') AS [name] --obviously, you'll likely need a larger length
FROM (VALUES(@XML))V(X)
     CROSS APPLY V.X.nodes('result/subject') r([subject])
     CROSS APPLY r.[subject].nodes('name') s([name]);
```